# Generate new $$hashkey on angular push

Tags: angularjs

I want to push an item in my array object, and this is my code:

```
<li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in widgets" style="border: #ddd 1px solid;">
   <a ng-click="list.push(item)" style="padding:2px;position: absolute;z-index: 1000;right:2%;top: 2%;" class="add-widget-to-sidebar pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true" style="margin:2px 10px;"></span>
    </a></li>
```

and $scope.widgets already has hashkeys on every object, and what I want to do is every time I push a new item in my list, I want a new $$hashkey for it. I already tried doing this and it didn't work:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('list', function() {
        $scope.temp = []
        rand=0;
        angular.forEach($scope.list,function(value,key){
            value.$$hashKey = rand++;
            console.log(rand);
            $scope.temp.push(value);
        }); 
        $scope.list = $scope.temp;
        console.log('temp');
        console.log($scope.temp);
        console.log('list');
        console.log($scope.list);
        $scope.resize(); 
    });
```

Comment: Why do you care about the hash keys? Either you want to push the item, and you just push it, or you want to push a copy of the item, and you should thus create a copy (angular.copy() helps), and push that copy. You shouldn't bother with $$hashKeys. They're angular internal stuff. What are you really tying to achieve?

Comment: If i add the same item twice, they are bind together, and I don't want that.

Comment: So, you need to create a copy. They are not "bound together". They are two references to the same, unique object. Changing tha $$hashKey won't change anything. You will still have two references to the same unique object in your array.

Comment: so how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: As I said, angular.copy(). Read the documentation. Note that I'm assuming that you want a copy. You still haven't told what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the mention of the method `angular.copy()` ! It looks a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in widgets track by $id($index)">
    .....
  </li>
```

this will remove $$hashkey on your ng-repeat